# I can not download some extentions like Pritier, Live preview to vscode

Tags: html, css

someone can help me understand why I can download some extensions o  VScode, some of them appeared as still in development.

I need to download extensions like prettie, Live preview for my homework, I am  a new student of Web development.

Comment: Hi, we don’t really have enough to go on yet. Your question probably needs to be tagged  vscode to attract someone with that knowledge and please include an example of how you are trying to download extensions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help with doing this.